# SQL User-Defined table Type in INTO statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, user-defined

I want to Create a table @tablename with data from a User-Defined Table Type but I get the error

> Must declare the table variable "@tablename"

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Prod_EntTable]
@paramEntTable typeTableEnt readonly,
@userid int
AS
BEGIN
Declare @tablename nvarchar(20)
Set @tablename ='mynewtable' + @userid
SELECT EntID, Title INTO @tablename FROM @paramEntTable
END
```

I tried with EXEC as

```
EXEC (N'SELECT EntID, Title INTO mynewtable' + @userid + ' FROM ' + @paramEntTable)
```

the error was

> Must declare the table variable "@paramEntTable"

How can this be fixed?

Comment: You can't `select into` a variable. `select into` will store the result-set into a new table.

Comment: As has been mentioned in the comments in an answer, however, the real problem is your design. *Why* do you want a table for each individual user? This is a design flaw. The user id should be a column in a table, and there should be 1 table, not part of the table's name with many tables.

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a new table every time based on the inputted @userid. This scenario required dynamic TSQL to execute and we can not concatenate type parameter in string so this seems impossible to me.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I need to repeat what has been said in the comments, the whole idea of what you want to do here is a design flaw. Creating a table for each user is wrong; it fundamentally breaks basic design rules. Each user should *not* have their own table, instead you should have *one* table which has a column `UserID`. Then when you need data for a specific user, you use a `WHERE` to filter to that data.

If your goal is to stop users being able to access the data of other users then use [Row Level Security](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/row-level-security?view=sql-server-ver15) (RLS) to ensure that a user can only access to rows they are supposed to.

That being said, you can achieve what you want, but first, to explain why what you have isn't working.

1. ```sql
   Set @tablename ='mynewtable' + @userid
   ```

   This will error, as `@userid` is an `int`, and `'mynewtable'` is clearly a literal `varchar`. As such `'mynewtable'` will be implicit cast to an `int` and you get the following error:

   > Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'mynewtable' to data type int.
2. ```sql
   SELECT EntID, Title INTO @tablename FROM @paramEntTable
   ```

   SQL is *not* a scripting language, you *cannot* use variable to replace a  literal. The above, would not be parsed as "`SELECT` `INTO` the table with name of the value of the variable `@tablename`" but as "`SELECT` `INTO` the **table variable** `@tablename`". This would obviously fail, as you can't use `SELECT...INTO` to create and insert into a table variable; you have to `DECLARE` and `INSERT INTO`.
3. ```sql
   EXEC (N'SELECT EntID, Title INTO mynewtable' + @userid + ' FROM ' + @paramEntTable)
   ```

   This doesn't work because of point 1, and because `@paramEntTable` isn't in scope. Variables/parameters only exist in the scope they are defined in, they are *not* accessible from the outer or inner scopes. This is why the syntax `EXEC ({SQL Statement})` is frowned upon, you can't parametrise the statement. You should be using `sys.sp_executesql`.

So, what is the solution? Well, if you take the points above, and concatenate using `CONCAT`, **safely** inject your table name, and *parametrise* your dynamic statement, this will work. This is **not** tested, due to a lack of sample data and DDL (for `typeTableEnt`), so any errors you'll need to fix. I also *assume* everything is on the `dbo` schema, as the schema has mostly been omitted.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Prod_EntTable] @paramEntTable dbo.typeTableEnt READONLY,
                                      @userid int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TableName sysname, --Correct data type for object names
            @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

    SET @TableName = CONCAT(N'mynewtable', @userid); 
    SET @SQL = N'SELECT EntID, Title INTO dbo.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' FROM @paramEntTable;';

    EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@paramEntTable dbo.typeTableEnt READONLY', @ParamEntTable;

END;
GO
```

Answer (score -1):

I think, you should edit your code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Prod_EntTable]
@paramEntTable nvarchar(max),
@userid int
AS
BEGIN
Declare @tablename nvarchar(20)
Set @tablename ='mynewtable' + @userid
SELECT EntID, Title INTO @tablename FROM @paramEntTable
END
```

Comment: You can't use an `INTO` clause on a scalar variable. It makes no sense to try to store a dataset "into" a `varchar(20)`.

Answer (score -1):

Hey the main problem with your sp is that you didnt create the table in which you want to select into.
So First you need to create your Table if it isnt there.
And then you can generate the Input Statement.

Im Not sure about the dynamic Tablenames in direct sql querys, therfore i generate the `Select INTO` in a second variable and execute it like i would for the creation.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Prod_EntTable]
  @paramEntTable typeTableEnt readonly,
  @userid int
AS
BEGIN
   Declare @tablename nvarchar(20)
   Set @tablename ='mynewtable' + @userid

    IF Object_ID(@tablename) IS NULL
    BEGIN
       declare @createtablesql nvarchar(max);
       -- as a variable because of the dynamic table names
       SET @createtablesql = 'your create statement';
       EXECUTE sp_executesql @createTableSql 
    END

    declare @selectIntoSql nvarhcar(max);
    SELECT @selectIntoSql = CONCAT('SELECT EntID, Title INTO ', 
    @tablename,' FROM ', @paramEntTable);

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @selectIntoSql 

END
```

Comment: `@paramEntTable` is a table type parameter; you can't concatenate it to a scalar string.

Comment: @Larnu true but im to lazy to open the ssms to get it 100% right, i wrote this blind and i never worked with dynamic table names because i consider it bad design, because in the end you have 1.000.000 tables with 5 values each it just bloats up the database and makes it very hard to maintain it

Comment: But the problem is that as you've made a blind guess the syntax is wrong; this will generate an error. Most likely *"Must declare the scalar variable '@paramEntTable'"*